# Доступ к API соцсетей

Tags: мобильные-приложения, api, ios

Здравствуйте! Такая ситуация. Нужно в мобильном приложении использовать доступ к соцсетям VK, Facebook. Twitter, причем обращаться к ним будет сервер (по полученному от приложения токену), а потом передавать данные в приложение. 
Мне интересно, какой максимальный срок жизни токена для этих сервисов (а также YouTube). Для VK я нашел информацию о том, что можно получить безлимитный токен. Как насчет Facebook. Twitter, YouTube? И будут ли работать токены на сервере, если я их получил на другом ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Facebook и Twitter токен получают интегрированные в настройки аккаунты, вам же всего лишь нужно получить доступ к этим аккаунтам, с помощью native: Social.framework, Accounts.framework. Для ВК и Одноклассников вроде нужно через некоторое время обновлять сессию с помощью renewCredentialsForAccount